# Phalcon Model not accepting variable

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, models, phalcon

I have a trouble when i try to verify if a user exists in the database.

```
$login = $this->cookies->get('login');
$loggedinas = $login->getValue();
$user = Users::findFirstByUsername($loggedinas)
```

This returns:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /public_html/app/views/charactersheets/create.phtml on line 27, referer: localhost/charactersheets
```

However if i use this:

```
$user = Users::findFirstByUsername("pentacore")
```

it works, and i've checked so that the cookie contains the right username with var_dump($loggedinas) (returns string(32) "pentacore", thank you silkfire) which returned pentacore so... what could be the problem?

Comment: Try `var_dump()` the `$loggedinas` variable, what do you get?

Comment: @silkfire var_dump($loggedinas) returns string(32) "pentacore"

Answer (score 0):

From Phalcon @ Phalcon Framework Forum:

It could be that cookie's decryption adds extra trailing spaces so you have to probably do:

```
$login = $this->cookies->get('login');
$loggedinas = trim($login->getValue());
$user = Users::findFirstByUsername($loggedinas)
```